# how can we replace span contenteditable in regex?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
let qs='<span contenteditable="true">sssss</span>'
```

i want to replace span to sssss.

after replacing word should look like
+++sssss+++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex `/<span.*>(.*)<\/span>/g` and string replace (or replaceAll) with captured group.

```
qs.replace(/<span.*>(.*)<\/span>/g, '+++$1+++')
```

```js
const regex = /<span.*>(.*)<\/span>/g;

let qs='<span contenteditable="true">sssss</span>';

const newQs = qs.replace(regex, '+++$1+++');

console.log(newQs);
```

Comment: without using * how can we make it?